# Flutter build IOS error IconTreeShakerException: Font subsetting failed with exit code -9

Tags: ios, flutter, build

Before that I still build IOS normally with the command: `flutter build ipa`. Until I upgraded to Flutter 3.3.10. It suddenly throws an exception and I can't build IOS.

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Target release_ios_bundle_flutter_assets failed: 
IconTreeShakerException: Font subsetting failed with exit code -9.


Encountered error while archiving for device.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes as @Janis awnser as hot fix. Or use my way, go to `System Preferences` -> `Security & Privacy` -> Allow Font-sub

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered the same issue. Maybe it is related to some IconData not being declared as const, but I didn't find anything like that in my project, so for now I append `--no-tree-shake-icons` to my release build command, maybe that works for you too.